# How to test if a Object is a Java AWT component?

Tags: java, awt

I have a method wich will receive a String array containing a list of classes. I have to check wich one is a Java AWT component and return a list with the instances of those components. But I am stuck at testing whether or not a Object is a java Awt component or not. Can you please help me ! Thanks

EDIT: Thanks! It works with .isAsignableFrom() methot. I knew about the instanceof operator but didn't tought it would work.!

Comment: Do you already have the objects? Or just class names?

Comment: Easiest way: resolve the class name to a `Class` and do an `instanceof` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the class hierarchy *without creating instances first*:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);  // errors out for bad name
if (Component.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the object then you can get the class name using the [getClass method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

> Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is
>   the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the
>   represented class.

The other option is to use the [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html) operator if you have to check for a specified class like Component. The `instanceof` operator can be used if you want to check that the object is of a specific type.